# Python: HTTP caching using 'CacheControl` not working

Tags: python, api, http, cache-control, etag

I'm using python 3.6 with `requests` module for API consumption and `CacheControl` module for caching the API response. I'm using following code but cache does not seems to be working:

```
import requests
from cachecontrol import CacheControl

sess = requests.session()
cached_sess = CacheControl(sess)

response = cached_sess.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
```

Every request to this URL returns the `200` status code (instead of `304` status code) and the same resource is requested each time even though the `ETag` headers is same and `max-age` was still valid. The API returns following cache related headers:

```
'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=14400'
'Expires': 'Sat, 04 Feb 2017 22:23:28 GMT' (time of original request)
'Etag': 'W/"160d-MxiAGkI3ZBrjm0xiEDfwqw"'
```

What could be the issue here?

**UPDATE:** I'm not sending `If-None-Match` header with any API call, do I manually have to do it or `CacheControl` module should take care of it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Use a cache implementation to persist the cache between runs of the program.

```
from cachecontrol.caches import FileCache

sess = requests.session()
cached_sess = CacheControl(sess, cache = FileCache('.web_cache'))
```

Also, ensure you're using a recent CacheControl release. CacheControl has only [cached resources served as `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol/pull/106) since 0.11.7:

```
$ curl -si https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users | fgrep -i transfer-encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

> Every request to this URL returns the `200` status code

This is what you'll see when CacheControl is working correctly. The return of a cached response, or use of a 304, is hidden from you as a client of the code. If you believe that a fresh request is being made to the upstream server, consider something like:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

to see what `cachecontrol.controller` and `requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool` are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using `CacheControl` latest version 0.12.0. Instead of default `DictCache` method I've also tried `FileCache` method, but this does not seems to be working either. However, `DictCache` method does work, only if I send `If-None-Match` manually with the request. Further, the response does not have `Transfer-Encoding` header but has `Content-Encoding: gzip`, can it be the issue?